# Get results for Log.i in a TextView in Android

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

How can we retrieve and display in a `TextView` for example messages that we have in `LogCat` ?

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layer Direction : " + direction);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layer ShortPD : " + pr);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layer Stack : " + stackL3);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layer Header : " + msgL3);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layer Data : " + strData);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layer BCCH : " + bcchString);
```

So, I display these messages in `LogCat` and right now I want to display them in some `TextView`'s in my application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer this link.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_textview_control.htm

Follow these steps:
1] Create XML for define textview.
2] Create Activity Class for set text on TextView.

Answer (score -1):

just find your textview in layout and type

```
textView.setText( "Layer Direction : " + direction);
...
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to retrieve the LogCat in a method and after that I want to transfer it to onCreate ... I want to try with a StringBuilder, to put the data in a String and pass it with the context ? Is this possible ?

Comment: i dont understand what you want... when you have strings you can show them thought log or show in textview...

Comment: I use tabs ;) and for transferring the data from an activity to the PagerAdapter I use 'setTag' and 'getTag' in onCreate ... and I want to transfer some data displayed in LogCat from a method to onCreate and after that to transfer it to the PagerAdapter ... I realised it with a simple String, but I don't know how to retrieve the LogCat and to transfer it to onCreate ...

Comment: I think, reading of logcat is possible only on rooted devices, so you can not read logcat normally... But also I think, when you need read logcat to retreive and pass data to lower layer of your app, you just doing something wrong... Can you tell, from what you want to retreive data and why is your way throught logcat ? Can you show some code, that are you trying to do?

Comment: ok :) thank you for your answer :) the way is not throught logcat ;) I have the following code

Comment: if (status != 0) {
               if (gsmMsgFieldLength == 0) {
                   Log.i(LOG_TAG, " L2 Frame read on CCCH \n");
               } else {
                   if (dir == 1) {
                       direction = "UpLink";
                   } else if (dir == 0) {
                       direction = "DownLink";
                   }

                   if (fr != 0) {

Comment: bcch = ((frame[Library.Offset_In_OTFrame + gsmMsgFieldLength + 3] & 0x03) << 8) + (frame[Library.Offset_In_OTFrame + gsmMsgFieldLength + 4] & 0xFF);
                       bcchString = String.format("%s", bcch);
                   }


                   String strData = BasicFunctions.bytesToHex(frame, Library.Offset_In_OTFrame + 3, gsmMsgFieldLength);

                   if (pr == 0) {
                       layer3MessageDecoder(layer_len);
                   } else {
                       layer3MessageDecoderShortPd(layer_len);
                   }   }

               
           } else ...

Comment: and for example I want to retrieve the 'direction' from this method and to pass it to onCreate ... I tried with StringBuilder, but it displays me nothing ;) I try to retrieve the direction with a StringBuilder and after that to pass it by using context to onCreate ;) If I use a simple String I can pass it, but I don't know how to retrieve the direction from my method ;)

Comment: if this code is in some other class and you have an object in activity just call getDirection() ... but from code you pasted I can not see what's going on...

Comment: for example, from the following code I just want to retrieve the direction and after that to pass it to onCreate. I display it in LogCat, but I don't know how to retrieve the direction, to put the direction in something ;) for passing it, I can use the context I think:                                                                                                                if (dir == 1) {
   direction = "UpLink";
   } else if (dir == 0) {
   direction = "DownLink";
    }

Comment: I use that part of code in a method and I want to pass it to onCreate :) for passing, I use the context, but can I retrieve the direction in a builder or buffer or something else ?

Comment: you are going tottaly wrong. if this code is in main activity, you can get this variable directly. if it's in some object, you use getter. but you can not put this in oncreate. you first must understand activity life cycle. so if this code is triggered in oncreate you can use this variable directly and if this code is in some action for example click listener you use it there.

Comment: ok :) thank you :) is not in the main activity ;) so, I have to use getter